# Что делает vctip.exe?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

Чисто случайно обнаружил, что среди сообщений об ошибках Windows много ошибок `vctip.exe`. Начал копать, выяснил, что это что-то в составе Visual C++ 2015, но что эта программа делает - в Интернете не пишут (или я не нахожу). Подсунул вместо нее заглушку - ей не передается никакая информация (ни в командной строке, ни через стандартный ввод). Вызывается при компиляции, но самой компиляции не мешает.

Стало просто интересно. Кто-то может подсказать, что это и зачем?

PS

```
File   : vctip.exe
SHA256 :  46f89793d5df3ca4a24e1b1ee196ea150b105a7e10947c57e336509a12731c2f
SHA1   :  3648f03dc77946835fce7b54f358434a6f13bbc3
MD5    :  fd442c307bc454d3930eaf6ec878fd36
CRC32  :  cfa16112
```

Comment: А SHA1 файлика можете дать? Чот не могу у себя найти на посмотреть :-(

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов См. в ответе. Сам файл у меня лежит в `\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vctip.exe`

Comment: Судя по "Microsoft® VC compiler and tools experience improvement data uploader" - должен отсылать данные на сервера MS. Так что я бы на процесс сборки Wireshark'ом посмотрел...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да вот есть у меня подозрение, что это телеметрия какая-нибудь... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно [данному ответу](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/418402/view.html) на форуме поддержки, это клиент телеметрии, который отправляет в Microsoft сведения о выполняемых в студии действиях и возникающих ошибках ([Visual Studio Customer Experience Improvement Program](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-experience-improvement-program?view=vs-2017)). Ему ничего не передается через командную строку, потому что он берет всю информацию в режиме реального времени из Event Tracing for Windows.

Visual Studio Customer Experience Improvement Program по умолчанию включена, но ее можно отключить способом, описанным [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-experience-improvement-program?view=vs-2017#opt-in-or-out):

1. В меню выбрать **Справка** -> **Отправить отзыв** -> **Параметры**.
2. Выбрать параметр "Нет, я не хочу участвовать"